# How to store Pandas DataFrame with Int64 to MS Access table

Tags: pandas, ms-access, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, sqlalchemy-access

I'm on python 3.11.8, sqlalchemy 2.0.25, sqlalchemy-access 2.0.2, pyodbc 5.0.1, pandas 2.2.1, MS Access 2016.

Connection looks like:

```py
engine = sa.create_engine("access+pyodbc://@my_accdb")
conn = engine.connect()
```

Here's part of my code:

```py
    tab20 = pd.read_sql_table("table_name", conn)[['col1', 'col2']]
    print(tab20.head())
    df = tab20.dropna()
    print(df.head())
    print(df.dtypes)
    df = df.astype('int64') # this runs okay
    df_dtypes = {
        "col1": sa.types.BigInteger,
        "col2": sa_a.LongInteger
    }
    print(df.dtypes)

    df.to_sql("new_table", conn, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=df_dtypes)

    conn.commit()
```

col1 contains value of 11-digit numbers, col2 contains value of 5-digit numbers.
Originally in MS Access, col1 values are `"Large Number"`, col2 values are `"Number"(field size: long integer)`
I would like to keep their data type as in MS Access.
Currently, I'm able to convert column dtype to `'Int64'`. When I try to write to ms access table, it got error:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HYC00', '\[HYC00\] \[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver\]Optional feature not implemented  (106) (SQLBindParameter)')
\[SQL: INSERT INTO \[new_table\] (\[Col1\], \[Col2\]) VALUES (?, ?)\]
\[parameters: \[(72001956300, 601), (72001956400, 601), (72001956500, 601), (72001956600, 601), (72001956700, 601), (72001956800, 601), (72141957600, 601),
(72003430100, 602)  ... displaying 10 of 168212 total bound parameter sets ...  (2198000100, 99927), (2275000300, 99929)\]\]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
```

It works with convert to `'float64'`, but I would like to make them integers.
I've also tried directly using `pyodbc`, but receives same error.
This happens to all situations when I try to write int64 to sql table.
How can I fix this?

**UPDATES**:
I'm able to run without error by removing `astype()` line, but this leads me to more error (`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal UTF-16 surrogate`) in other functions.

**UPDATES 1**:
Now I doubt about my source data. Getting unicode decoding error even I went with `to_csv`. Might be the converting problem? (I don't like Access, try to persuade my boss not using it

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607364/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-into-access-db

Comment: Hmmmm. It works a bit? I can manually do INSERT without error popping up, but this leads me to other errors. My current way is giving up on this table, run the query in Access and manually change the type. Thanks tho

Comment: Depending on the exact version of Access 2016, BigInt (64-bit integers) may or may not be supported (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-large-number-data-type-5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70). Please provide both the exact version and the database version. It may be either Access or the database file do not support large numbers.

Comment: I'm on Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20290) 64-bit . Now I doubt my source data may have issues.

Comment: related: https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/%5Bpandas%5D-working-with-64-bit-integer-(BIGINT)-values